# httpd make install file mod_authn_file.so was not found error

Tags: apache, installation, makefile, aix

APR, APR-util, PCRE Everything installed properly, but when it came to httpd, configure and make happened properlyand make install gave error. Below are errors of make install. I'm using AIX 7.2, and I tried below combinations.

1. apr-1.5.2, apr-util-1.5.4, pcre-8.44, httpd-2.4.54
2. apr-1.7.0, apr-util-1.6.1, pcre-8.44, httpd-2.4.54
3. apr-1.7.0, apr-util-1.6.1, pcre-8.44, httpd-2.4.41
4. apr-1.5.2, apr-util-1.5.4, pcre-8.44, httpd-2.4.41

Every time same error at the end. Please help...

```
Making install in aaa
rm -f /home/randompath/Apache/modules/mod_authn_file.so
/home/randompath/Apache/apr-1.7.0/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=install install mod_authn_file.la /home/randompath/Apache/modules/
find: bad status-- /home/randompath/mod_authn_file.so
find: cannot chdir to </etc/cluster/locks> : Permission denied
find: cannot open < /etc/corrals >
find: cannot chdir to </etc/iscsi> : Permission denied
find: cannot chdir to </etc/security> : Permission denied
find: cannot chdir to </etc/tunables> : Permission denied
find: cannot chdir to </usr/lib/boot/network> : Permission denied
find: cannot open < /usr/lib/corrals >
find: cannot chdir to </usr/lib/drivers/crypto> : Permission denied
find: cannot open < /usr/lib/methods/wio >
find: cannot chdir to </usr/lib/security/tnc> : Permission denied
install: File mod_authn_file.so was not found.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.

Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.
```

I Installed in below sequence.

apr,
apr-util,
pcre,
httpd

and to install
./configure,
make,
make install

--prefix and --with- I used in configuration and I'm installing httpd with --with-mpm=prefork

Comment: This `find` is very strange, find out where does it come.